# Select Statement in Where Clause Returning More Than 1 Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 to write a procedure and I am receiving this error when trying to run this select statement.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I think it has something to do with the `Select` statement in the `where` clause but I'm not too sure.

The procedure:

```
select top 100  
   Team.ID,
   Team.Name,
   sum(Results.Points) as PointsTotal
from            
   Results
inner join 
   Teamon Results.TeamID = Team.ID
where           
   Results.TeamID = Team.ID
   and Results.Date > DATEADD(YY, -1, GETDATE())
   and Results.Date <> (Select Min(Date)
                        from Results
                        Inner join Competition on Competition.ID = Results.CompetitionID
                        Inner join Team on Team.ID = Results.TeamID
                        where CompetitionID = 3
                          and TeamID = Team.ID
                          and Date > (DATEADD(YY, -1, GETDATE()))
                        group by Team.Name
                        Having Count(Competition.ID) > 1)
group by        
    Team.ID, Team.Name
order by        
    PointsTotal desc
```

Comment: The error message is pretty self explained. Your subquery `Select Min(Date)... Count(Competition.ID) > 1` will return more than 1 row of result. Then if you append this result to your original where clause, it is like, where `DATE = 1 2 3 4 5 6...`

Comment: LOoks like you have two or more records withe same min(date). Personally I would suggest using a where not exists clause instead. Correlated subqueries tend to be the worst way to get information from a performance standpoint and can generally be avoided using a differnt construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your WHERE clause is grouping by Team.Name and selecting the MIN(Date) you are going to return the minimum date for each team (based on the other criteria too).  If you are using a <> operator you can only have one value on the other side of that operator, if you need more than one value use the NOT IN operator instead.

If you need the individual teams to match up with the minimum date, i would LEFT JOIN to a subquery on the TeamId and MinimumDate, and then in the WHERE clause I would make sure that one of the fields that you are joining on IS NULL (which would indicate that the join condition did not match the sub-query, and that will filter out any records with that team and the minimum date).  The query would look something like this:

```
select top 100  Team.ID,
                Team.Name,
                sum(Results.Points) as PointsTotal
from            Results
inner join Team on Results.TeamID = Team.ID
left join (
      Select    Team.Id, Min(Date) AS MinDate
      from  Results
      Inner join Competition on Competition.ID = Results.CompetitionID
      Inner join Team on Team.ID = Results.TeamID
      where CompetitionID = 3
      and   TeamID = Team.ID
      and   Date > (DATEADD(YY, -1, GETDATE()))
      group by  Team.ID
      Having    Count(Competition.ID) > 1
  ) MinimumDateQuery ON
  Results.TeamID = MinimumDateQuery.Id AND
  Results.Date = MinimumDateQuery.MinDate

where           Results.Date > DATEADD(YY, -1, GETDATE())
and             MinimumDateQuery.Id IS NULL
group by        Team.ID, Team.Name
order by        PointsTotal desc
```

Comment: Hi, this works in some instances but not in all. Is the TeamID in the where clause associated with the TeamID in the first select? I need it to exclude different dates for each team, thanks. @MDiesel

Comment: IN this case it is not.  You need to write a join to accomplish this.  I will edit my answer above to show you @user3279193

Answer (score 2):

If the subquery may return more then one result you should replace the `<>` operator with `not in`

Comment: Hi, this works in some instances but not in all. Is the TeamID in the where clause associated with the TeamID in the first select? I need it to exclude different dates for each team, thanks. @bwt

Comment: no, because the Team table is used in both the inner and the outer query with the same name.
You have to give it a different alias, so you can unambigously reference it.
Beware that using [correlated subqueries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) may have impact on performances.
You may also replace the subquery with a join.

Answer (score 0):

That `group by` inside the subquery will make it return one row containing the minimum value of `Date` for each value of `Team.Name`.

Consider simply this:

```
|----------------------|
| Name     | Date      |
|----------------------|
|A         |2001-01-01 |
|A         |2001-01-02 |
|B         |2001-01-01 |
|B         |2001-01-02 |
|C         |2001-01-02 |
```

Executing a query

```
SELECT MIN(Date) FROM Results GROUP BY Name
```

Returns

```
|----------------------|
| No column name       |
|----------------------|
|2001-01-01            |
|2001-01-01            |
|2001-01-02            |
```

Comment: Each team has different dates to disable, would this be unique for each team?